# There is Not Enough Memory To Complete this Action

Tags: excel, vba, memory

I've written the below code to modify a speadsheet that has tens of thousands of lines. Whenever I run the code, it burns through the lines fast enough, will complete about 10k lines in 3-4 minutes or so. But every time I run it, it gets to about line 25K or so, and crashes, telling me I don't have enough memory, and will suggest upgrading to 64-bit. I have a macro that created the sheet without incident, and it's much more complex, so seems odd this code crashes it. Anything in this code that you'd think would cause my issue? Or is 64-bit likely the right fix?

```
    Sub TPOUploadCADUplicate()
'This takes the TPO Mass upload sheet and duplicates it below for Canada. Unlike above, it doesn't do anything to the US part on top
Dim Answer As String
Dim BigMarkup As Double
Dim CAPrice As Double
Dim Cost As Double
Dim i As Long
Dim rn As Long
Dim rn2 As Long
Dim SKUCount As Double
Dim STMarkup As Double
Dim USPrice As Double
Dim lr As Long
Dim DescLen As Integer

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

'Make sure you didn't accidentally leave the description length column in
If Cells(1, 3) <> "VENDOR # (9 SPACES)" Then
    DescLen = MsgBox("Yo, bro. I think you left the description length column in. You want to delete that shit? I can't proceed otherwise.", vbYesNo)
    If DescLen = 6 Then
        Columns(3).Delete
    ElseIf DescLen = 7 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

Columns(6).NumberFormat = "#.00"
'Loop through each one, doing the math from the TPO price calculator Connie has
If Cells(2, 1) = "" Then Exit Sub
rn = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

rn2 = rn + 1
rn = 2
SKUCount = rn2 - rn
For i = 1 To SKUCount
    Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & i & " of " & SKUCount & " - " & Format(i / SKUCount, "0%")
    Rows(rn2).Value = Rows(rn).Value
    USPrice = Cells(rn, 4)
    If USPrice * CAMarkup < 20 Then
        CAPrice = Round((USPrice) * CAMarkup, 1) + 0.09
    Else
        CAPrice = WorksheetFunction.RoundDown((USPrice) * CAMarkup, 0) + 0.99
    End If

    Cells(rn2, 4) = CAPrice
    Cells(rn2, 6).Value = Cells(rn2, 6).Value * CAMarkup
    Cells(rn2, 22) = "CAM"
    rn = rn + 1
    rn2 = rn2 + 1

Next i

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .StatusBar = False
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the only line in here that costs a lot of memory would be `Columns(3).Delete`. Nothing else looks significantly costly but I'm not familiar with `StatusBar`. Do you have a `Worksheet_Change` event on this sheet? i notice that you don't disable events during this macro. It might be running the event 4x per loop, wasting resources.

Comment: Where are you setting CAMarkup I'm guessing it's just a constant somewhere? Also, if you're familiar with debugging in Excel. I would be curious to know what value rn2 gets to. It seems it's set to the last row plus one and then basically has the SKUCount added to it as the program iterates through the loop. Accessing a cell about 1mil down may throw the error you're seeing. @Toddleson's suggestion is good. I would disable events Application.EnableEvents = False just make sure to re-enable them after it has ran and if it runs into an error have it re-enable it too.

Comment: @Toddleson: The status bar just gives me some semblance of progress. I might try turning off events, though. Thank you.

Comment: @Byrd CAMarkup is a public constant I have that's used in several worksheets. RN2 gets to double of RN. For instance, if I have 25000 lines to start, I'll eventually have 50,000 when I'm done, and that's where RN2 will end up.

Comment: @Byrd This particular iteration had nearly 50k lines, so I was almost ay 100k total. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Might be better (faster) to read all the data to an array, then work on the array, before putting it on the sheet after the existing data.

```vb
Sub TPOUploadCADUplicate()
    
    Dim ans
    Dim CAPrice As Double
    Dim SKUCount As Double
    Dim STMarkup As Double, CAMarkup As Double
    Dim USPrice As Double
    Dim DescLen As Integer, ws As Worksheet, arr, lr As Long, lc As Long, r As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'best to be explicit about which sheet you're working with
    
    'Make sure you didn't accidentally leave the description length column in
    If ws.Cells(1, 3) <> "VENDOR # (9 SPACES)" Then
        ans = MsgBox("Yo, bro. I think you left the description length column in. " & _
                "You want to delete that shit? I can't proceed otherwise.", vbYesNo)
        If ans <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
        ws.Columns(3).Delete
    End If

    ws.Columns(6).NumberFormat = "#.00"
    
    lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row         'last row
    If lr = 1 Then Exit Sub 'no data?
    lc = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last column
    
    CAMarkup = 1.1 '<< for example
    arr = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(lr, lc)).value 'copy the existing data as an array
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1) 'loop over the array and make adjustments
        USPrice = arr(r, 4)
        If USPrice * CAMarkup < 20 Then
            CAPrice = Round((USPrice) * CAMarkup, 1) + 0.09
        Else
            CAPrice = WorksheetFunction.RoundDown((USPrice) * CAMarkup, 0) + 0.99
        End If
    
        arr(r, 4) = CAPrice
        arr(r, 6) = arr(r, 6) * CAMarkup
        arr(r, 22) = "CAM"
    Next r
    
    'put the data on the sheet
    ws.Cells(lr + 1, "A").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).value = arr

End Sub
```